# Cannot specify query parameters on this resource

Tags: postman

Im using Postman to do a bulk API request to send data into SF.
This is still working in Production, but from Jan 30th it stopped working on 2 different sandboxes.
I've already tried to change the profile to Sys Admin, no success.

This is the issue:
[image]

Body is:
{
"state" : "UploadComplete"
}

This is a get request, to show that I still have access to the Sandbox:
[image]

Post method and Ingest still working
[image]

I was not able to find any other solution online, any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

After speaking with SF support this was due to a maintenance and it was fixed yesterday evening (Feb 7th).
Unfortunately the developers couldnt do anything since its something on SF backend.
Fortunately its solved and I hope this finds useful to anyone who also faced this issue.

Comment: same issue still on 1 of my sandboxes, 16 feb 2024